# JQuery count down timer is not counting down

Tags: ajax, jquery, countdown

I have a jQuery count down timer which have to count from 30:00 minutes to 00:00. But showing and stucked at 29:59 
Here is my code:

```
var now = new Date();
var newDateObj = new Date(now.getTime() + 30 * 60 * 1000)
$("#countdowntimer").countdown({
    date: newDateObj.toGMTString(), //Counting TO a date
    htmlTemplate: "%{m}:%{s}",
    onComplete: function (event) {
        $(this).html("Completed");
    },
    leadingZero: true
});
```

PS: I am using `jquery.jcountdown1.3.js` plug-in

What's issue here?

Comment: which countdown plugin are you using?

Comment: To my knowledge jQuery does not come with a countdown method. What plugin are you using?

Comment: refer this plugin http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: @Kathiravan but that coundown plugin has no `date/htmlTemplate/onComplete/leadingZero` options

Comment: ya i told to refer the link. May be the plugin will helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created [a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/olaxoj/2/edit) for you using keith-wood countdown. It can do what you want it to do, but the api is slightly different.

Let me know if you have any more queries

Comment: I am not supposed to refer the online URL as source

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: I am not supposed to give `src="http://cdn.strategiqcommerce.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/1.6.1/jquery.countdown.min.js"` and `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"`

Comment: you can always download the files and reference them locally.

Comment: I did the same, i downloaded `src="http://cdn.strategiqcommerce.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/1.6.1/jquery.c‌​ountdown.min.js"` and copied to a javascrit file. It didnt work!

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be working fine if you use the following countdown plugin-version:
https://github.com/tomgrohl/jQuery-plugins/raw/f0040f6e0c9942abac22590eccfa6f2897a61abf/countdown/script/jquery.jcountdown1.3.min.js

Tested with firefox....